# How do i translate this to prepared statement

Tags: prepared-statement

How do I convert this to a prepared statement using mysqli & php?

> $db->executeQuery('Update product Set prod_ops_txt = replace(prod_ops_txt, "/' . $img . '.jpg","") Where prod_ops_txt Like ("%/' . $img . '.jpg%")');

i'm looking to do something like this:

> $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('Update product Set prod_ops_txt = replace(prod_ops_txt, ?,"") Where prod_ops_txt Like ("%?%")');
>
> $thisImg = '/' . $img . '.jpg';
>
> $stmt->bind_param('ss', $thisImg, $thisImg);
>
> $stmt->execute();
>
> $stmt->close();

Comment: defining $db is immaterial to the question.

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit of fiddling but I finally found the proper syntax myself:

> $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('Update product set product_options_text = replace(prod_opts_txt,  ? ,"") Where prod_opts_txt Like (?)');
>
> $thisImg =  '/' . $img . '.jpg';
>
> $thisImgMatch =  '%/'. $img . '.jpg%';
>
> $stmt->bind_param('ss', $thisImg, $thisImgMatch);
>
> $stmt->execute();
>
> $stmt->close();